# Simple way to get current memory usage from Guppy

Tags: python, guppy

tl/dr: how do I get the current memory usage of my python program using Guppy?  Is there a simple command?

I'm trying to track memory usage in a python program using guppy.  This is my first usage of guppy, so I'm not very sure of how it behaves.  What I want is 
to be able to plot the total usage as "time" progresses in a simulation.  This is a basic bit of code for what I can do:

```
from guppy import hpy
import networkx as nx

h = hpy()
L=[1,2,3]

h.heap()

> Partition of a set of 89849 objects. Total size = 12530016 bytes.
>  Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
>     0  40337  45  3638400  29   3638400  29 str
>     1  21681  24  1874216  15   5512616  44 tuple
>     2   1435   2  1262344  10   6774960  54 dict (no owner)
```

But I would like to just know what the current size is (the 12530016 bytes).  So I'd like to be able to call something like `h.total()` to get the total size.  I'd be shocked if this doesn't exist as a simple command, but so far, looking through the documentation I haven't found it.  It's probably documented, just not where I'm looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = h.heap()
x.size
```

returns the total size. For example:

```
from guppy import hpy
import networkx as nx

h = hpy()

num_nodes = 1000  
num_edges = 5000  
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(num_nodes, num_edges)

x = h.heap()
print(x.size)
```

prints

```
19820968
```

which is consistent with the `Total size` reported by

```
print(x)
# Partition of a set of 118369 objects. Total size = 19820904 bytes.
#  Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
#      0  51057  43  6905536  35   6905536  35 str
#      1   7726   7  3683536  19  10589072  53 dict (no owner)
#      2  28416  24  2523064  13  13112136  66 tuple
#      3    516   0  1641312   8  14753448  74 dict of module
#      4   7446   6   953088   5  15706536  79 types.CodeType
#      5   6950   6   834000   4  16540536  83 function
#      6    584   0   628160   3  17168696  87 dict of type
#      7    584   0   523144   3  17691840  89 type
#      8    169   0   461696   2  18153536  92 unicode
#      9    174   0   181584   1  18335120  93 dict of class
# <235 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```